# how to set padding or margin to linear layout?

Tags: android, layoutparams

I have a linear layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_menu"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="70px"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="@drawable/footer_bar"
android:gravity="center" >
</LinearLayout>
```

When i set condition

```
if (constant.getscreenresolution() >= 800) {
    //i want to make it height * 2
}
```

So how to set the `layout params`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hope this helps you

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout_param= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.fill_parent,
                height * 2);
mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_menu);
mLayout.setLayoutParams(layout_param);
```

Comment: return me this exception
`05-28 13:41:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(16380): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
`
my layout is linear but why involve relative?

Comment: Alan, You should use RelativeLayout params  instead of LinearLayout params

Answer (score 12):

For padding:

```
LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_menu);
mLayout.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.ll_winfowindo);
int left= (int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._18sdp);
int top=(int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._22sdp);
int right=(int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._18sdp);
int bottom=(int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._34sdp);
mLayout.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing this.  First you're using pixels (px) instead of device independent pixels (dp)  Doing things like this create UIs that only work for specific device screen configurations.  You need to learn how Android addresses the variations in screen densities so that your app is screen density independent.  Start here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: i know, that why i had created 2 sets of layout

Answer (score 0):

Add Margin to Linear Layout :-

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);
```